# Federate AMQP 091 and 1.0 Queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, azure-eventhub

Is it possibile to federate amqp 091 Queue with an amqp 1.0 Queue?
For instance: federate RabbitMQ queue with Azure Event Hub queue?